# How to define custom template for Wagtail streamfield Document block?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

We have a model defined with a `StreamField` that allows a `DocumentChooserBlock` as follows:

```py
class CustomPage(Page):
    body = StreamField(
        [("document", DocumentChooserBlock()),]
    ...
```

Our page template renders the `CustomPage.body` field as follows:

```html
{% block content %}
    ...
    {% include_block page.body %}
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

By default, the PDF document uploaded via the `StreamField` renders as a link.

How can I override the rendered output for the document link in the `CustomPage.body` `StreamField`, so that I can render the PDF in line with a JavaScript PDF widget?

If this is a common need, I would be interested in publishing a Wagtail extension for other projects to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a `template` argument to DocumentChooserBlock:

```
class CustomPage(Page):
    body = StreamField(
        [("document", DocumentChooserBlock(template='myapp/blocks/document.html')),]
```

Alternatively, if you're going to be using this in multiple places, subclass DocumentChooserBlock and set `template` in its inner Meta class, then use that new class in place of DocumentChooserBlock:

```
class DocumentEmbedBlock(DocumentChooserBlock):
    class Meta:
        template = 'myapp/blocks/document.html'


class CustomPage(Page):
    body = StreamField(
        [("document", DocumentEmbedBlock()),]
```

Within the template, `value` will refer to the Document object, so you can refer to the document's properties via `{{ value.url }}` or `{{ value.title }}`:

```
<h2>{{ value.title }}</h2>
<iframe src="{{ value.url }}"></iframe>
```

Comment: Might it be necessary/possible to check the document MIME type? E.g., in the case where various document formats might be present.

Comment: I'll try the `document.content_type` property: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/f8299885aa916becb9109c881f3ab28408af794e/wagtail/documents/models.py#L169-L170